# Python: installation error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install `Python 3.5.2` on my `Windows Vista Home Premium x32`. While installing it Windows pops up a window saying `"Python stops working"`. The installation continues, ends and it says it was successfull. Of course it wasn't because when I want to run python an error occurs saying that it can't find `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python 3.5.2` can't install because `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll` is missing from your computer.You have to install `Windows Updates: Go to Start - Control Panel - Windows Update` Check for updates Install all available updates. After the updates are installed, restart your computer, and then try to install `python 3.5.2`

Comment: I have all of the updates and drivers installed. I also got the same error when I try to uninstall Python.

Comment: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll is Microsofts Universal 
CRT.  You don't have one.  You need to install it. Get it here:
[http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234]